# How to add class by referring to array in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to addclass in `2nd` row, by referring to array and its index.

I prepared `array` and all that remains to add class by referring to `index`.

through my work, it didn't work well.

How can I achieve them?

Thanks

```js
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;

html += '<tr>';
for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
  i = i + 1;
  html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
}
html += '</tr>';

for (let w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
  html += '<td class=color></td>'
  }
  html += '</tr>';
}
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

const arr = [1, 2, 10, 11, 14].map(String);

$("td .color")
  .filter(function() { return $(this).index(arr); })
  .addClass('red');
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.color{
 padding:5px;
 }
 
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any space between the *tag* name and the *class* if both refer the same element. You can use `includes()` to check if the *index + 1* is exists in the array or not.

Try the following way:

```js
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;

html += '<tr>';
for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
  i = i + 1;
  html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
}
html += '</tr>';

for (let w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 15; d++) {
  html += '<td class=color></td>'
  }
  html += '</tr>';
}
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

const arr = [1, 2, 10, 11, 14];

$("td.color")
  .filter(function() { return arr.includes($(this).index()+1); })
  .addClass('red');
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.color{
 padding:5px;
 }
 
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tidy up your loops a bit by first building the indexes, and then use backquote to clean up your html template.

Note: you should be using double quotes for attributes eg class="color"

```
const columnCount = 15;
const columnIndexes = [...Array(columnCount).keys()];  // make array of indexes
const rowsCount = 1;
const rowIndexes = [...Array(rowsCount).keys()];

const html = 
    `<table>
        <tr>
            ${columnIndexes.map(c => 
                `<td data-layer="0"><div>${c + 1}</div></td>
            `)}
        </tr>
        ${rowIndexes.map(r => 
            `<tr>
                ${columnIndexes.map(c => 
                    `<td class="${r % 2 === 0 ? 'red' : ''}"></td>`
                )}
            </tr>`
        )}
    </table>
    `
```